# Godot 4 Open XR causing program to crash before starting

Tags: virtual-reality, godot, gdscript, openxr

I am on Godot v4.0.stable.mono.official of Godot and trying to start a VR project.  The only script I have in the project looks like this:

```
extends Node3D  

var interface : XRInterface  

func _ready():  
    print('start') #never printed 
    interface = XRServer.find_interface("OpenXR") 
    if interface and interface.is_initialized(): 
        get_viewport().use_xr = true
```

I am using a Quest 2 through virtual desktop to connect through steam VR and I am on Windows 11

When I try to run the debug the window opens for about 10 seconds with the Godot logo, then closes before ever getting to the first frame and running the _ready function. This does not happen when I do not enable OpenXR and XR Shaders, it just opens in flat mode of course. When I don't connect a headset as well, it gives me a warning to connect my HMD then starts in normal flat mode.

If you need any more info just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Godot 4.0.1.stable.mono, it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).